# Appgyver Steroids splashscreen linger duration

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, steroids

Before I knew the existence of AppGyver Steroids, I was building an app with PhoneGap, everything was going on smoothly. Recently, I tried to use AppGyver Steroids to build my app, so I ported the project from PhoneGap to Steroids following the official guide found on the web. I could successfully debug my app on my MacBook afterwards, no problems at all.

I have created an app with AppGyver Steroids that shows a Microsoft Bing Map with several hundred pushpins attached. When I wanted to test it on my Samsung Galaxy S2, I deployed it to the cloud and built the apk file with the Ad Hoc version. Most of the build settings are left as default.

Later, when I install it on my device and run it, the default "AppGyver" splashscreen lingered for around 15 seconds or longer before the Bing Map showed up.

I would like to know:

- if there are any ways to adjust the duration of showing the splashscreen
- the reason of such a long loading time if this is not a "setting-related" issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, running Android 4.1. However, on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini, the splashscreen disappears much quicker, after around 5 seconds. The steroids native code is not public so it is difficult/impossible to find the source of this problem without asking Appgyver staff, but in any case they are [working on a new Android client](http://blog.appgyver.com/heartbeat/steroids/android-as-a-first-class-citizen/) which will almost certainly fix this kind of thing. I think unfortunately it's a case of hang tight... if you want to try asking the Appgyver staff they are usually very responsive: http://forums.appgyver.com/

Comment: Ah ok. Well maybe keep an eye on it, I know the AG team are working ridiculously hard to iron everything out!